# Strange Behaviour in SSIS - ODBC SOURCE component

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, odbc

I have a package where I fetch records between a date (using an expression) from a MySQL Database and insert them into our SQL Server DWH. This package has been executing without any strange behaviour for several months, however within the last two days we've noticed that sometimes/randomly the ODBC Source component only retrieves the first row of the data set.

I have:
 - investigated all the custom properties of the component
 - checked the query expression
 - date parameters are passed as string

I've exhausted all options and I don't know what else I can try.

[image: Custom properties]

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behavior in debug mode, or does it only ever happen when the package is running unattended?

Comment: This situation occurs in a random fashion both from debug and the live environment. I execute the same package with the same parameters - sometimes it works correctly, other times only 1 row is inserted.

Comment: And when it happens in debug mode, it doesn't throw any errors or warnings?

Comment: Not at all. The process is in fact marked successful. Not even warnings! Can it be the ODBC Driver? The query is a bit complicated; however correct.

Comment: Never heard of any similar problems with ODBC, but you could try switching to OLEDB and see if it goes away.

Comment: After several tests we've concluded that there's a high probability that it's the MySQL ODBC driver.As a work around, I included some logic to re-extract data if only one row was returned and a count query does not return 1 row. Thanks for all your help.